# Logon failed for login due to trigger execution

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-express, localdb, mdf

I try to add the "mdf" database file to the project, I get an error.
How to fix the error?

**Error:**
*The attempt to connect to the database*
failed; the following information was received:
Logon failed for login HOME-PC\Root' due to trigger
execution.
Changed database context to master'.
Changed language setting to us_english.*

`MSSQLLocalDB` is installed together with `Visual Studio`

I did not install `SQL Server`.
I would not like to install `Sql server management studio` and `SQL Server`, but if the problem cannot be solved in another way, then I can do it.

**I use:**

- Visual Studio Community 2019;
- Visual Studio 2022;
- Windows-10x64;

I found a solution, but I don't know if it suits me and where to enter commands. I'm afraid to make it worse
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/218811/logon-failed-for-login-due-to-trigger-execution

When I try to fully post a question, `stackoverflow.com` gives me comments on the design. I don't understand how to eliminate these comments.
That's why I'm posting the question in an online editor.

**Follow the link -> [[Detailed question.](https://hackmd.io/hz6-qIk8R1qWX4tbs5BF-Q)]**

Answer (score 13):

For me **Error 17892** went away by deleting the old LocalDb instance that is created by default when visualstudio is installed and creating a new one with the same name.

So follow these steps.

1. open powershell on your machine and run the following commands.
2. ```powershell
   SqlLocalDb info
   ```

   it should list all the localdb instance names in your machine. The result should show just one result
   `MSSQLLocalDB`
3. ```powershell
   SqlLocalDb delete "MSSQLLocalDB"
   ```

   it should delete your existing instance that is not working which will allow for a new instance by the same name to be created. **Don't worry it will not delete your database files**. The result should show :
   `LocalDB instance "MSSQLLocalDB" deleted.`
4. ```powershell
   SqlLocalDb create "MSSQLLocalDB"
   ```

   it should create a new fresh instance with the default name. The result should show :
   `LocalDB instance "MSSQLLocalDB" created with version 15.0.4153.1.`
5. ```powershell
   SqlLocalDb info "MSSQLLocalDB"
   ```

   Checks to see the status of your newly created instance. Don't bother that the instance will be shown as stopped, this is normal. It will start upon connection. The result should show:

   ```plaintext
   Name:               MSSQLLocalDB
   Version:            15.0.4153.1
   Shared name:
   Owner:              MACHINE_NAME\username
   Auto-create:        Yes
   State:              Stopped
   Last start time:    29/06/2022 3:16:59 pm
   Instance pipe name:
   ```

Thats it!

Now open VisualStudio or the MSSQL Management Studio and connect to your instance it should be fine. You can attach any existing database (Your mdf and ldf files will sill be there under your `%USERPROFILE%` folder.

You can read more about the [sqlLocalDb.exe here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5612/getting-started-with-sql-server-2017-express-localdb/)